# sql database design - select & check boxes

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am designing a database for a form which contains many select boxes and check boxes lists.

I am unsure whether to populate these lists from a table in the database or from the select html text.

as part of db design best practice which is the preferred method.

Comment: If you are asking where you should get the options for the SELECT elements - if there is any chance you will ever need to add a new OPTION it's best to store the data in a table. For very simple SELECT elements that contain something like "Yes" and "No" you can just hard code that in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect the form elements (checkboxes, lists) are likely to change often, or are conditional (based on configurable permissions/roles), then they should come from a database.
However, if they are mostly static (rarely change, not dependent on configurable permissions), then you should hard-code them.  The big benefit of hard-coding them is less traffic on your DB.  This will yield the best performance.